# vector<char> with zeros to string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a

```
vector<char> sectionData;
```

and I would like to see its content.I try the following

```
string sectionDataStr = string(sectionData.begin(),sectionData.end());
```

But I get only part of the sectionData presented in the string,since sectionData contains zeros.What can I do,if any case I want to read entire data to string?

**I can`t use std::cout**
Thanks

Comment: You *are* copying the entire string. You just fail to *print* it in a meaningful way. If you just did `std::cout << sectionDataStr` you should in fact get everything.

Comment: You *successfully* copied the entire string. Try a `fwrite(sectionDataStr.c_str(),1,sectionDataStr.size(),stdout);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem doesn't exist. Here's a simple demonstration:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::string { 'a', '\0', 'b', '\0', 'c' } << std::endl;
}
```

Now inspect the output:

```
$ ./a.out | hexdump -C

00000000  61 00 62 00 63 0a
```

```
##         a \0  b \0  c \n
```

As you can see, it's all there.

---

Alternatively (following your edit):

```
#include <cstdio>

std::fwrite(sectionDataStr.data(), sectionDataStr.size(), stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the string, but with the output. Depending on what you use, the output routine may stop at the first 0 in your string. If you don't want that, then you might need to convert the buffer for output using something like:

```
std::replace( sectionData.begin(), sectionData.end(), '\0', ' ' )
```